# server first byte time or (Improve server response time)

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, server-response

Im running a wordpress site on amazon EC2 (m1.medium) .

Im using CDN serve files and using W3C total cache to increase performance ( i cannot use page cache because im serving dynamic content and using PHP sessions.

I am using mod_deflate to keep good performance.

Problem i have is that from time to time the server response time is very slow , looking at the server monitor I see no special problem CPU is under 40%

Sometimes first byte is sent after 1.5 seconds and sometimes it can go up to 6-8 seconds.

What can i do here ?

Comment: It could be an issue with the instance or configuration, but it could also be an issue with the network between you and your instance. I would look at traceroutes and see if there is any packet loss or high latency within the network.

Comment: well i need more info on how to do that "traceroutes" thanks

Comment: Trace route is a console tool, the command `tracert` on windows and `traceroute` on any other system. Just run this `traceroute <ip-address>`.